# Select items in TypeORM migration

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to add one more column to a table. Additionally, I have to insert an object in created column based on existing data. The problem is when I'm modifying the table, I'm trying to select all items from the table but the query is stuck (see "Get events" in log).

Here is my code:

```
    async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
        Logger.debug('Start migration');
        Logger.debug('Table modification');
        await queryRunner.addColumn(
            'sport_events',
            new TableColumn({
                name: 'url_keys',
                type: 'hstore',
                isNullable: true,
            }),
        );

        Logger.debug('Create repo');
        const repo = queryRunner.connection.getRepository(SportEvent);

        Logger.debug('Get events');
        let events = await repo.createQueryBuilder().getMany();

        Logger.debug('Modify events');
        events = events.map((event) => {
            const keys = {};

            for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(event.name)) {
                keys[key] = generateURLId(val as string, key);
            }

            event.URLKeys = keys;
            return event;
        });

        Logger.debug('Save modified events');
        await repo.save(events);

        Logger.debug('Done');
    }
```

Log:

```
[Nest] 25628   - 07/17/2020, 12:00:28 PM   Start migration +504ms
[Nest] 25628   - 07/17/2020, 12:00:28 PM   Table modification +0ms
[Nest] 25628   - 07/17/2020, 12:00:28 PM   Create repo +454ms
[Nest] 25628   - 07/17/2020, 12:00:28 PM   Get events +0ms
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you add an explicit `select(...)` to your query builder before you call `.getMany()`?

Also is this query going to return a manageable number of results to handle in one shot like this?

Comment: The same behavior. Currently, I have 15 records in DB. So amount of data shouldn't be a problem. Even If I'm trying to select one item it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem too. Committing the transaction then restarting another prevents this.

```js
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "user" ADD "luck" integer`);

    await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();

    const users = await User.find();
    await Promise.all(
        users.map((u) => {
            u.luck = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
            return u.save();
        })
    );

    await queryRunner.query(
        `ALTER TABLE "user" ALTER COLUMN "luck" SET NOT NULL`
    );
}
```

It's worth noting if you don't start another transaction, the migration will work but will output an error in the console as presumably `typeorm` calls `commitTransaction` on the `queryRunner` after the migration function has resolved.